# download file through coding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to save a file in my application which I have created with code:

```
NSArray *arrayPathsForImg =
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                      NSUserDomainMask,
                                      YES);

NSString *pathForImg = [arrayPathsForImg objectAtIndex:0];
pathForImg = [pathForImg stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.txt"];
[self.importUrlData writeToFile:pathForImg atomically:YES];
```

Now I want to download it to my iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean by download? Access the file from within your app or fetch it from outside?

Comment: ya from my app, i can acces it in my app but i want to download it and store at some other place.

Comment: First, stop using the word *download*.  You should edit your question and use the word **save**.

Comment: Describe other place: A server or a different folder/filename?

Comment: yes Black frog..............................

Comment: at any place i want to save that file so i can see the changes in it which i made through code.

Comment: If you just want to inspect the file during development, use the Xcode Organizer to download your app's data (or, if you're using the Simulator, locate the directory where the Simulator stores app data).

Comment: ya i can find it in my simulator but whats about my iphone?

Comment: As I said, use the Xcode Organizer, select your device, select the application on the device and then click to download that app's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant "read" the file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.txt"];
```

And now use a `initWithContentsOfFile:` method. For example I used the code above to read from a property list and used the following code to get the data into a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```